# Does using dynamic state in a pipeline cause slowdown?

Tags: vulkan

I was wondering about using a pipeline with dynamic viewport state to handle changing the rendering resolution of my vulkan program.

Comment: That's Implementation-dependent. My opinion is I would not expect the slowdown to be tragic, if there is any at all. Especially on Desktop GPUs. Though there MAY theoretically be a slowdown, which is the reason why there is a choice given in the API.

Comment: I am guessing it has no slowdown because video games tend to use dynamic resolution to gain more fps

Comment: Guessing is pointless (which is why I don't dare to make an Answer to this). Of course reducing pixel amounts gives massive perf gains for typical pixel shader heavy games. And that would drown any slowdown from dynamic state (and potential blit this technique may need). You simply need to measure (on per-GPU basis) if you are curious.

Comment: Only thing I find safe to assume without measuring is that changing the dynamic state is same or faster than binding different pipeline with that (now static) state changed. And that on massive desktop GPUs "Dynamic state changes are relatively lightweight" as one NV presentation slides put it.